# Add Specfic Namespace to appsettings.json - Serilog ASP.NET Core 3.1

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, serilog

I followed a tutorial that gets you to set all the `Serilog` config up in `appsettings.json`; however, I cannot get my `WebAppLogger.Startup` to output any messages:

```
{
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "Serilog": {
    "Using": [],
    "MinimumLevel": {
      "Default": "Warning",
      "WebAppLogger.Startup": "Verbose",
      "Override": {
        "Microsoft": "Warning",
        "System": "Warning"
      }
    },
    "Enrich": [ "FromLogContext", "WithMachineName", "WithProcessId", "WithThreadId" ],
    "WriteTo": [
      { 
        "Name": "Console",
        "Args": {
          "outputTemplate": "{Timestamp:G} {Level} {Message}{NewLine:1}{Exception}"
        }
      },
      {
        "Name": "File",
        "Args": {
          "path": "Logs/log.txt",
          "outputTemplate": "{Timestamp:G} {Level} {Message}{NewLine:1}"
        }
      },
      {
        "Name": "File",
        "Args": {
          "path": "Logs/log.json",
          "formatter": "Serilog.Formatting.Json.JsonFormatter, Serilog"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I have tried adding `"Using": [{"WebAppLogger.Startup": "Verbose"}]` but this crashes the app.

I have found nothing on the `Serilog` docs that relates to using `appsettings.json`.

Also, is there a way I can completely suppress the `Microsoft` and `System` messages?

Comment: Hi  docs are in: https://github.com/serilog/serilog-settings-configuration/blob/dev/README.md

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `Using` field of the `appsettings.json`, you have to specify the sinks that you'll be using.

For example, if you're writing to the `Console`, you should specify the full name of the class including the namespace (in this case `Serilog.Sinks.Console`), provided that you installed the [NuGet package of the sink](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Serilog.Sinks.Console), of course.

e.g.:

```
{
  "Serilog": {
    "Using":  ["Serilog.Sinks.Console"], // <<<<<<<<<<##############
    "MinimumLevel": "Debug",
    "WriteTo": [
      { "Name": "Console" }
    ],
    "Enrich": ["FromLogContext", "WithMachineName", "WithThreadId"],
  }
}
```

You can see examples in the GitHub repository:

- [https://github.com/serilog/serilog-settings-configuration](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-settings-configuration#serilogsettingsconfiguration--)
- https://github.com/serilog/serilog-settings-configuration/tree/dev/sample/Sample

---

You can supress `Microsoft` and `System` messages by using [Filters](https://github.com/serilog/serilog/wiki/Configuration-Basics#filters) (e.g. `ByExcluding`, `ByIncluding`). In the [sample of the Serilog.Settings.Configuration repo](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-settings-configuration/blob/dev/sample/Sample/appsettings.json#L67) there's an example of how to configure it via `appsettings.json`.

Comment: Great! Thank you.